# How do I disable a test from running in a subclass in TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

(Update: After I reported this, the TestNG team [confirmed](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1712)  [the](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1709) [bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/testng-users/d_m7S0upJl8/ViLggu13AgAJ).)

Normally, ignoring a class can be done with `@Ignore` or `enabled=false`

This does not work on a subclass where test methods are defined in its superclass (and where the subclass defines its specific functionality in hook methods). See `ChildClassTest` below.

Note that `@Ignore` is specific to JUnit whereas TestNG uses `enabled`.

Base class

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParentClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        hook();
    }

    protected void hook() {};
}
```

Child class

```
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Ignore;

@Ignore
public class ChildClassTest extends ParentClassTest {
    @Override
    protected void hook() {
        Reporter.log("ChildClassTest#hook()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `@Ignore` annotation

Comment: `@Ignore`  annotation is apparently specific to JUnit and unavailable in TestNG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore a class in testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923801/ignore-a-class-in-testng)

Comment: Ignoring a class in TestNG is easy. Just use enabled=false. But what if the class is a *subclasss* of a test class and has no methods of its own? That is my question

Comment: @user7 it turns out that this identifies a real bug, confirmed by the TestNg team!

Comment: For reference, [`@Ignore` exists](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#ignore-tests) in newer versions, but in your case it seems to be, well _ignored_, possibly as the effect of the bug you mentioned. However, it seems that overriding the method from the superclass with `@Test(enabled = false)` is honoured, but it's NOT listed as skipped. Tested with v6.14.2.

Comment: Morfic thank you. Right, @Ignore is ignored in this case. Overriding the actual @ Test method might work as described, but here we have a hook method implementation in the subclass, and no @ Test methods

Comment: No problem. Yes, I got from the start that there are no tests in the subclass. I was simply suggesting to temporarily override the desired method in your subclass without adding a body (or maybe a comment to make it less weird) and add `@Test(enabled = false)`, as a workaround until a proper solution is released. This way it will be skipped while the rest will run as needed, hopefully, with a minimum of effort

Answer (score 2):

Been doing some brainstorming out of curiosity, and came up with the workarounds below tested with v6.14.2. I personally prefer the first one, being cleaner, more elegant, flexible and easier to maintain and extend.

**context**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldRun() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotRun() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotRunEither() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

---

**1)** Using listeners - create a `TestListenerAdapter` & annotation to skip methods with certain names: flexible, clear, easy to reuse and identify for removal. The only downside is that you have to pay attention to method names for typos.

**Annotation**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SkipMethods {
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

**TestListenerAdapter**

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

public class TestSkippingListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // get the skip annotation
        SkipMethods skipAnnotation = result.getMethod().getInstance().getClass().getAnnotation(SkipMethods.class);

        // if the annotation exists
        if (skipAnnotation != null) {
            for (String skippableMethod : skipAnnotation.value()) {

                // and defines the current method as skippable
                if (skippableMethod.equals(result.getMethod().getMethodName())) {

                    // skip it
                    throw new SkipException("Method [" + skippableMethod + "] marked for skipping");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Subclass**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

// use listener
@Listeners(TestSkippingListener.class)

// define what methods to skip
@SkipMethods({"shouldNotRun", "shouldNotRunEither"})
public class MyTestSkippingInheritedMethods extends MyTest {

}
```

**Result**

[image: skip by listener]

---

**2)** Override methods from superclass and throw `SkipException`: pretty clear, no possibility of typo, but not reusable, not easily maintainable & introduces useless code:

```
import org.testng.SkipException;

public class MyTestSkippingInheritedMethods extends MyTest {

    @Override
    public void shouldNotRun() {
        throw new SkipException("Skipped");
    }

    @Override
    public void shouldNotRunEither() {
        throw new SkipException("Skipped");
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image: skip by override]